# What class should a UIPageViewControllerDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, protocols, subclass

For My App I need an object that conforms to the `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` protocol.

I am wondering what that would look like.

Right Now It Looks Like

```
@implementation MyGRDeligate : NSObject <UIPageViewControllerDelegate>
```

Is This correct? Is there a `UIDeligate` Object? Also, Do I Have To Have the `<UIPageViewControllerDelegate>` part or just implement the methods? Also, I have a Page View COntroller That Is It's Own Delegate, Can It Be a `<UIPageViewControllerDelegate>` As Well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any `UIDelegate` class. Any object can be a delegate, as long as it:

1. Says that it conforms to the delegate protocol (the `<UIPageViewControllerDelegate>` part).
2. Implements any required methods in the `.m` file. (`UIPageViewDelegate` doesn't have any required methods, but some delegate protocols do).

Your page view controller could be the delegate, it would have access to (possibly) required objects. In general, a table view controller and it's delegate are the same object.

Answer (score 1):

That looks fine, or you could take an existing class and make it also conform to the protocol.   It's commonplace to have a controller of some kind conform to multiple delegate protocols so that it can coordinate operations between multiple views working on the same model.

For example, often the `UIViewController` subclass will take on the delegation authority for multiple objects and kinds of objects.  However, the flexibility in the system is there to allow you to create separate objects for some, or all, of your delegates, depending on your design pattern.